# Why do I have to use 'exportfs -a' always to mount nfs?

Tags: nfs

I have my Ubuntu system and a Raspberry Pi, which access Ubuntu via NFS.
For some reason, I always have to use 'exportfs -a' in Ubuntu, or else the raspberry will not be able to mount (shows `mount.nfs: mount system call failed`).

Is there something wrong with my NFS?

Comment: Always as in, after every reboot or after your re-connect the NFS right?

Comment: @Jobin after reboot only.

Answer (score 0):

It is essential to `exportfs -a` after you re-connect the NFS. From `man exportfs`:

```
-a     Export or unexport all directories.
```

That is, when you reboot your machine or connect a new NFS or dis-connect and connect a new filesystem as NFS, you will have to `exportfs -a`, there is nothing with your NFS.